# Convert SQL Query to Laravel Query - Laravel 7

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have query

```
SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

It worked perfect.I'm trying to convert it to Laravel query

```
$visitors = DB::table('visitors')->select(DB::raw('*'))
            ->whereRaw('created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK')->get();
```

I kept getting error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `visitors` where created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW() = INTERVAL 1 WEEK)

[image]

Can someone help ?

Comment: You are missing a `)` in whereRaw ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is missing ")" in SQL Query so it is not related to Laravel.

```
$visitors = DB::table('visitors')->select(DB::raw('*'))
        ->whereRaw('created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)')->get();
```

But why are you using raw SQL instead of Carbon?

```
$visitors = DB::table('visitors')->select(DB::raw('*'))
        ->where('created_at', '>', now()->subWeek())->get();
```

Also it would be good idea to make model Visitor (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Visitor extends Model
{
   //
}
```

And then your eloquent query will look like this

```
$visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subWeek())->get();
```

Comment: Your apostrophe placement is wrong at the end of `whereRaw` ;)

Comment: Yeah, no code color syntax while typing answer and there it goes :P

Comment: Yeah I like your updated version of your answer better :)

Comment: Of course not - laravel eloquent is making SQL query anyway :P But you use frameworks (like Laravel) to make life easier and code shorter and cleaner, so why not in this case?

Comment: I agree with you completely. Using it now. Thank-you.

Comment: @chojnicki Is what you suggest is making 2 queries under the hood ? I asked about that in details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61192650/how-to-optimize-query-statement-in-laravel-7